# How do I test for exceptions in if-statements in python?

Tags: python, function, exception, if-statement

i want to write a function to report the different results from another function
there are some exceptions among these results but I cannot convert them into if statement

example :

> if f(x) raise a ValueError, then my function has to return a string
>   'Value' if f(x) raise a TypeError, then my function has to return a
>   string 'Type

But I don't know how to do this in Python. Can someone help me out.

My Code is like this: -

```
def reporter(f,x):    

    if f(x) is ValueError():
        return 'Value'
    elif f(x) is E2OddException():
        return  'E2Odd'
    elif f(x) is E2Exception("New Yorker"):
        return 'E2'
    elif f(x) is None:
        return 'no problem'
    else:
        return 'generic'
```

Comment: WHY ARE YOU SHOUTING? ..... Seriously, please don't use all-caps. It's hard to read and makes our (mental) ears hurt.

Comment: I'm so so sorry about that..I'm just getting crazy about that. My homework will due tomorrow actually.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have [`try-except`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) to handle exceptions in Python: -

```
def reporter(f,x): 
    try:
        if f(x):  
            # f(x) is not None and not throw any exception. Your last case
            return "Generic"
        # f(x) is `None`
        return "No Problem"
    except ValueError:
        return 'Value'
    except TypeError:
        return 'Type'
    except E2OddException:
        return 'E2Odd'
```

Comment: Thanks! But I have not learned about this in my course. So maybe I cannot use it.

Comment: @user2010023 `try-except` is the only way to handle exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

```
def reporter(f,x):    
    try:
        if f(x) is None:
            return 'no problem'
        else:
            return 'generic'
    except ValueError:
        return 'Value'
    except E2OddException:
        return  'E2Odd'
    except E2Exception:
        return 'E2'
```

Answer (score 0):

You put your function call in a `try-except` construct like

```
try:
    f(x)
except ValueError as e:
    return "Value"
except E20ddException as e:
    return "E20dd"
```

The function itself does not return the exception, the exception is caught outside.